# What are jartmp files?

Tags: java, jar, tmp

I know it is probably a dumb question but I find [no results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jartmp) in SO and no relevant results in google ([here](https://www.google.com/search?q=Failed%20to%20load%20Main-Class%20manifest%20attribute%20from&rlz=1C1CHKZ_enUS433US433&oq=Failed%20to%20load%20Main-Class%20manifest%20attribute%20from&aqs=chrome.0.57j5j0l2.642j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#gs_rn=17&gs_ri=psy-ab&gs_mss=what%20is%20jart&tok=sgNByDJX_M64JXAm0XGBUw&pq=what%20is%20jartmp%20.tmp%20java%20jar&cp=14&gs_id=8y&xhr=t&q=what%20is%20jartmp&es_nrs=true&pf=p&rlz=1C1CHKZ_enUS433US433&sclient=psy-ab&oq=what%20is%20jartmp&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48340889,d.eWU&fp=4df16b97d5a5a5b0&biw=1856&bih=1019&bs=1) is the google search link where I searched 'what is jartmp').

I found there are many jartmp files in my folder and don't know why they exist:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1      0 Jun 11 14:28 jartmp1089103248955132063.tmp
-rw-rw-r-- 1  54935 Jun  6 03:21 jartmp1258300977464933918.tmp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 118685 Jun 26 22:47 jartmp1388010323455694859.tmp
-rw-rw-r-- 1  15643 May 29 16:45 jartmp1819063406633422416.tmp
-rw-rw-r-- 1      0 Jun 11 16:03 jartmp2142600141373219701.tmp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 197964 Jun  6 03:19 jartmp3480763606864988668.tmp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 126386 Jun 26 22:47 jartmp3533722093029133854.tmp
-rw-rw-r-- 1   7830 Jun  6 03:19 jartmp3713382469327367468.tmp
-rw-rw-r-- 1  55872 Jun 21 15:14 jartmp3950308579438275722.tmp
-rw-rw-r-- 1  39716 Jun 11 16:03 jartmp4311759817318348544.tmp
-rw-rw-r-- 1      0 Jun 11 14:31 jartmp499113526131437419.tmp
```

I tried to use `head *.tmp` to see the content of the .tmp files, but it seems that they are all binary files.  Can I know why these files are generated and whether it is safe to delete them?

And my java version is 1.6.0_24 for your reference.

```
java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't imagine a circumstance where a file with that name would contain valuable data.

But if you are really worried, try using the `file` command to attempt to identify the files' types ... based on their contents.

---

How are they generated?

Well the most likely culprit would be some command that creates or unpacks JAR files.  Try correlating the timestamps of the files with what you are / were doing at the time.  That would help you narrow it down a bit.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion.  It ends up being a `Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract`.

Comment: @keelar - well since a JAR file is a ZIP file, that fits.  If you were curious, you could attempt to unpack them, but I wouldn't be surprised if ZIP said they were truncated.

Comment: But the strange thing is either I used `jar -tf` or `unzip`, they both failed ... orz

Comment: (Told ya so :-) )  - They most likely resulted when the tool that was attempting to create a JAR file got killed or something.

Comment: I found I have two jartmp files just created within an hour, and during that time I was indeed trying to make jar files :#

Answer (score 0):

This could be result of `jar -uvf` operation on a jarred file to update a file to jar which is *not* present in actual path. This is just one of the reason I noticed where it shows this in shell/cmd o/p

`: no such file or directory` & ends up creating a tmp file (binary) file of pretty huge size.

Answer (score 0):

I started running into this issue with the Java 8 jar.exe when supplying files to update in an archive where one or more of the files didn't exist. For example,

```
%ProgramFiles%\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\jar.exe uvf0 ..\Desktop.jar Desktop\images\*.gif Desktop\reports\*.rep
```

where no file that matches the pattern `Desktop\reports\*.rep` exists, even though gif files in the other path do. In this case, the "jartmp" file remains and the jar file intended to be updated is left untouched. This is a change from Java 7, where jar.exe would happily replace the files it found and ignore the others.